# Can a usecase have repositories from different domains as dependencies, following the clean architecture principles?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, clean-architecture, use-case

Assume I have two models: Student and Course, so we have a simple many-to-many relationship here, i.e., each student can take many courses and each course has many students.

I also have a usecase for adding a Student to an existing Course, where I receive as input the Student id and the Course id, and add this pair to my Relationship table which is managed by a AddStudentToCourseRepository.

**The problem that I'm facing is the following**: If the client tries to add a student to a course that does not exist, my application needs to return an error. I though about adding the ReadStudentByIdRepository and the ReadCourseByIdRepository as dependencies of my AddStudentToCourseUsecase, so I can check whether both id's are valid before calling the AddStudentToCourseRepository.

**My question is**: Am I going against the clean architecture principles by doing that, I mean, is it a bad practice to have a usecase having repositories from multiple domains as dependencies ? And if I am, how would you guys proceed in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it a bad practice to have a usecase having repositories from multiple domains as dependencies ?

A use-case should not handle entities from different domains, there are other conceptual patterns to handle such situation. In your case, however, there are multiple aggregates considered to be within the same bounded context, so it is OK to add related repositories.

In order to apply validations (student/course exists, student not already registered to course etc.) you would probably want to have all repositories managed under a single transaction, and for that you should use the unit-of-work pattern.